# How to set shipping method using “cart_shipping.method” in magento api v1

Tags: api, magento, soap

I want to set shipping method using `"cart_shipping.method"` but it's giving me fetal error. Error message is `"Uncaught SoapFault exception: [1062] Shipping method is not available"`. I am using method like that

```
$result = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'cart_shipping.method', array(1402,'flatrate'));
```

Comment: have u added information regarding Customer, Customer Address and Product information to the currently existed cart or what ? And you please update that shipping method to "flatrate_flatrate" and let me know the result

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem because I was using test information which was not valid in the address call (cart_customer.addresses (SOAP V1) or    shoppingCartCustomerAddresses (SOAP V2)).

So try a valid address which also works in the front end. For example, if you use the wrong country, magento will probably think: shipping is not available for this country. And then throw the 1062 error you experienced.
Maybe you had the same problem.

(btw I am using this as an example: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6424/how-to-create-order-using-magento-web-services-in-php)